# Understanding supremum of ordinals. Differences between limit ordinal and successor ordinal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum, ordinals

I apologize for this naive question, but I'm new to set theory and I'm having a hard time figuring out properties of supremum of ordinals.

From here on out I will refer to $\alpha$ as a nonzero ordinal. 
If I understand correctly the following are equivalent.

1. $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal;
2. $\bigcup \alpha = \alpha$.

Moreover, in general we have that $\bigcup \alpha$=$\text{sup }\alpha$.

Now I don't understand one thing, if $\bigcup \alpha$=$\text{sup }\alpha$, this means that whenever $x\in\alpha$ we have that $x\in\bigcup\alpha$ (because $\bigcup\alpha$ is the supremum of $\alpha$). However by transitivity $x\in\bigcup\alpha$ implies $x\in\alpha$. So it seems to me that property 2. hold for all ordinals, limit and successor.

Now, I know that there is some problem in my understanding, but where?

Also, consider $6= \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5 \}$, is it correct to say that $\bigcup 6 = \{ 0,1,2,3,4 \} $ ? If so, the previous point $x\in\alpha$ implies $x\in\bigcup\alpha$ is not true (because $5\in 6$, but $5\not\in\bigcup 6$), but then I must be missing something about the supremum properties. I thought the supremum was the least of the upperbounds, so as an upperbound, whenever $x\in\alpha$ we should have $x\in \text{sup } \alpha$.

Comment: It's worth noting: Sup(X) = ∪X whenever X is a set of ordinals. It's a tad more general than what you are using. Similarly, if X is a nonempty set of Ordinals ∩X is the infininum of X. I think going through these two proofs will get you used to the concept. Also, it's worth proving that (1) and (2) are eqivalent.

Answer (score 5):

The thing is that $x\in\alpha$ only means that $x\leq\sup\alpha$. So, knowing that $\sup\alpha=\bigcup\alpha$ we have that $x\in\bigcup\alpha$ ***OR*** $x=\bigcup\alpha$.

Remember, an ordinal is itself a *set of ordinals*, and the supremum is not "the least one *not* in the set", but rather "the least one that is *greater or equal to all the elements of the set". So, when a set of ordinal has a maximum, that maximum is the supremum, which is exactly what happens at successor ordinals.

In particular, $\bigcup 6=5$.

Comment: This makes very much sense. Thank you very much, I still need to gain familiarity with this formalism :)

Comment: This is why the advice is to always work with the definitions as carefully as possible until you start getting the idea of how these things work. In this case, it seems, the mistake was not unfolding the definition of a supremum. But that's very understandable, since we usually meet that definition a long time before we meet ordinals, so it's easy to think we have a strong grasp on that, and then just miss something small.